# UIScrollView inside UIView in a xib file not scrolling

Tags: objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIView (xib file) the schema looks like this

```
 -UIview
 ----UILable
 ----UIButton
 ----UIScrollView
 --------UILable * 19
 --------UIButton * 10
 --------UISlider * 3
```

I've created an outlet to all the controls at myView that contains the xib object and initialized the frame and contentSize of the scroll view

```
//myXib file code
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
self.frame =  CGRectMake(0,y, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height); //320,800
self.scrollView.contentSize= CGSizeMake(320,2700);
```

loading and showing the view works but it doesn't scroll what am I missing

```
//myViewController code
self.viewXib = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myXib" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.view addSubview:self.myXib];
```

Comment: Looks ok. It shoul work. - just check once again is your scrollview is connected with IBOutlet and - isn't you done scrolling disabled or user interaction disabled in xib

Comment: @AngelVasa everything is connected and user interaction enabled both on the view and the scrollview and scrolling enabled in the scroll view and still it's not scrolling